# Electron default Notification - banner click working but not working when I click in action center! (Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, notifications, electron, electron-builder

I have done building my application fully on the election, but in this notification, I got stuck, when  app sends the notification and I click on the notification banner ~ the click function works well, but when I click the notification from the windows action center it not emit any action. Please Help.

```
app.setAppUserModelId('com.example.app');
let notification = new Notification({ title: 'Alarm limit exceed', body: NOTIFICATION_BODY })
notification.show()
notification.on('click', (event, arg)=>{
  console.log('clicked')
})

notification.on('failed', (event, arg)=>{
  console.log('failed')
})

notification.on('close', (event, arg)=>{
  notification.close()
})
```

Comment: How is the NSIS tag relevant?

Comment: Cause i have used eletron builder for build the app ~ where i have used nsis for Windows, i thought it can be building related issue

Comment: It is not......

Comment: ok thanks, removing tag